Does not Rebuild, Have to Rerun the Program
A new developer here. I am recently working with a package called calendar_view. However, when I try to make any changes, I have this issue where the program would not update or rebuild. If I need to see any changes, I have to rerun the program.
What is the issue here? I have been Googling and it says there might be some state management issues. But I feel stuck whenever I go through the build method and do not know what to fix.
Solving this would increase my workflow a lot! TIA
I tried to look into the build method and state management system, but I got confused.

You should add the code where you are creating the state, updating the state using whatever state management and where you are using it in the widget.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I just had to clone the package into my computer and have a localized version of the package, which worked out.
